# How to reload route with nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am fairly new to Vuejs and NuxtJS. right now i am building an app with sever side rendering using nuxt js.
I have a container layout with a "search input" and i wanted that when a user enters something on the it takes to me to the search page and on the search page it must show the input, and if i am on the search page and i enter and submit form it should also taken me to the search page
Below are two pages. container page and Search page

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <el-container>
      <el-header>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="../static/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="q" v-model="q">
          <button type="submit" @click.stop.prevent="submit()">Submit</button>
        </form>
     </el-header> 
     <el-main>
      <nuxt/>     
    </el-main>
    <el-footer></el-footer>
    </el-container>    
  </div>  
</template>

<script>
  export default {  
    data() {
      return {
        activeIndex: '1',
        activeIndex2: '1',
        searchQuery:'',
        a:'',
        q : ''
      };
    },
    methods: {
      submit(){
        console.log($nuxt.$route.name)

        //return location.reload();
         //if you want to send any data into server before redirection then you can do it here
        return this.$router.push("/search?q="+ this.q);
        //
        //this.$forceUpdate();
      },

      handleSelect(key, keyPath) {
        console.log(key, keyPath);
      }
    },
  }
</script>
<style>
.el-main {
    background-color: #E9EEF3;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .el-header{    
    height:100px !important;
    line-height: 100px !important;;
  }
.el-header, .el-footer {
    background-color: #303952;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
  }
.logo img{
  height:40px;
  width:auto;  
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  top:10px;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */ 
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

}

.bg-purple{
  background: red;
  height:23px;
}

html {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

</style>
```

Search Page

```
<template>
    <h2>{{searchResults}}</h2>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        searchResults:''
      };
    },
    methods: {

    },
    mounted: function() {
        var q = this.$route.query.q
        this.searchResults = q;
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For anyone dealing with this, look into Nuxt's [watchQuery](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-watchquery/).

Answer (score 4):

To refresh your current view, try something like:

```js
this.$router.push(
  {
    path: this.$route.path,
    force: true,
    query: {
      param1: 'value 1',
      param2: 'value 2',
    },
  },
  () => {
    this.$router.app.refresh()
  }
)
```

Answer (score -2):

So what your looking for is known as Programattic navigation and is fairly simple to do [Here's the offical docs for it](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html). Inside of the method you are executing when a user searchs or a life cycle hook occurs you can simple write:

```
this.$router.push('/path/to/what/i/want');
```

This will then make the router navigate to the desiered location.

> **Note you shouldn't be returning this in your example.**

Specfically:

```
 submit(){
    console.log($nuxt.$route.name)

    //return location.reload();
     //if you want to send any data into server before redirection then you can do it here
    return this.$router.push("/search?q="+ this.q);
    //
    //this.$forceUpdate();
  },
```

Here you will be returning back `this.$route.push("/search?q="+ this.q);` Which leaves you in a state where you haven't actually ran this piece of code but rather returned it into the void.

Comment: if you looked at the source code i have used `this.$router.push('/path/to/what/i/want');`

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis If you read you shouldn't be returning this.. By doing so you won't actually change routes.

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis Updated answer to clarify further.

Comment: So lets say if i am on the target page "Search" and it has the same container layout with an input box ..so when i submit the form should it refresh the page like default behavior? if yes, doesnt happen with me
Because i am creating a search feature with server side rendering how can i send the data to the server and show results in the search page ? Any ideas? TIA

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis It shouldn't refresh, just because the data is server side rendered does not mean it will cause a page refresh, it just changes how the data is loaded.

Comment: Because i am creating a search feature with server side rendering how can i send the data to the server and show results in the search page ? Any ideas? TIA

Comment: Typically you'd send off a post request from your form on the page using something like `axios` and you'd promise the returning value. Once the value has returned from the server you would then update your component (If you have a bigger application probably a store update which would update the component) which shows the resulting search data.

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis If I've answered your question, you can mark it as correct :-)

Comment: It's unclear but it's not the same page 'that when a user enters something on the it takes to me to the search page and on the search page' - op's original post. @monokrome

Comment: @monokrome Would you mind explaining how I'm wrong? kind of seems like a redundant downvote / comment.